# Why is TraversableOnce.toSeq returning a Stream?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Here is an example:

```
scala> val xs = List(1,2,3).toIterator.toSeq
xs: Seq[Int] = Stream(1, ?)
```

A sequence is a materialized collection (it's a `List` by default), so I expected that `toSeq` would return a `List`, not a `Stream`

The implementation is in TraversableOnce,

```
  def toSeq: Seq[A] = toStream
```

why is it not overridden in TraversableLike?

Comment: Since it's not necessary to consume the iterator to get a valid `Seq`, why would you? There's always `toList`, `toVector`, etc. if you really want them.

Comment: Also, you really should just pretend you don't know that the underlying implementation of the `Seq` you get back is `Stream`. If you care, use a different `toX` method.

Comment: Travis, you could have the same argument for toIndexedSeq(). IndexedSeq is also a trait, just like Seq. List(1,2,3).toIterator.toIndexedSeq returns a Vector, which is the default implementation of IndexedSeq. I agree that List(1,2,3).toIterator.toSeq returning a List "may" be a bit too specialized, but I guess that keeping the semantics correct would be more important.

Comment: But it's not possible to write a valid `IndexedSeq` implementation that doesn't require consuming the iterator. There's not really any "default implementation" for either `Seq` or `IndexedSeq`—there's the one returned by `apply` on the companion object, but that's not some kind of special status. Also knowledge about which subtype is used is of course not statically available, and it's subject to change.

Comment: It's also not possible to write a valid Seq implementation that doesn't require consuming the iterator. So why have different semantics for toSeq and toIndexedSeq? On another hand, in our case, iterator.toSeq returns a Stream. Why a Stream?

Comment: But `Stream` _doesn't_ have to consume the iterator, and it's a `Seq`. The contract of `IndexedSeq` requires constant-time access by index, which means we do have to pull all elements out of the iterator.

Comment: In any case we're not really talking about the _semantics_ of `toSeq` and `toIndexedSeq`—that's completely captured by their return types. We're talking about implementation details.

Comment: Travis, makes sense. I did not realize that Stream is a Seq. Stream is not shown in the scala collection type hierarchy tree images...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scala supports infinite iterators, and `Stream` is the simplest `Seq` for possible infinite data.

```
Iterator.from(1).toSeq
```

terminates (if only a part of the collection is used), but

```
Iterator.from(1).toList
```

will never terminate.

You don't want do break code, if an equally valid decision would not. 
The `toSeq` method doesn't know the origin of the Iterator, therefor it must assume that it could be infinite.

The Docs "explain" this decision like this:

> Converts this traversable or iterator to a sequence. As with
>   toIterable, it's lazy in this default implementation, as this
>   TraversableOnce may be lazy and unevaluated.
>   Note: will not terminate for infinite-sized collections.

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/?_ga=1.200291566.1390086478.1406220121#scala.collection.Iterator

Comment: `Iterator.form(1)` creates an infinite sequence representing the natural numbers

Comment: Right. "Stream is the simplest Seq", even if this is not obvious, it does explain everything.